# click en GMSPolygon swift con Googlemaps

Tags: google-maps, swift3, map

Tengo un GMSPolygon visible en el mapa de Googlemaps.
Quiero hacerle click (tap) y que la consola me devuelva un mensaje.

```
 // ##### Polígonos


    let polygonEspaña = GMSPolygon(path: españa)
    polygonEspaña.fillColor = UIColor(red : 0.25, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.05);
    polygonEspaña.strokeColor = .black
    polygonEspaña.strokeWidth = 2
    polygonEspaña.map = myMapView
    polygonEspaña.isTappable = true


}

 //  END VIEW DID LOAD




// ###### Click Country


func myMapView(_ myMapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    print("User Tapped Layer: \(overlay)")
}
```

Comment: ¿Recibes algún mensaje de error? ¿Cómo falla lo que tienes?

Comment: No recibo errores, simplemente no funciona nada.

Creo que el problema es al implementar el GMSMapViewDelegate que ya he implementado en la clase y en teoría esta es la funcion:

private func myMapView(_ myMapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
        print("User Tapped Layer: \(overlay)")
    }


Gracias Álvaro.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!

Parece que el menú desplegable.

```
 RevealViewController
```

me está fallando cuando aplico el

```
GSMapViewDelegate.
```

Recordad agregar esto:

```
 myMapView.delegate = self
```

Sin esté menú funciona correctamente, aunque el texto que recibo en la consola es la información completa del polígono y no el texto del polígono.

Sigo trabajando a ver si puedo cambiar esto.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente. añadí la siguiente propiedad a los GMSPolygon

```
 polygonEspaña.title = "España"
```

y la función

func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {

```
    print("\(overlay.title)")
```

Ahora al hacer click en el país me sale : Optional("España")